# sort views comments by vote result keeping thread

Tags: 7, views, comments, rating

I want to show comments of nodes ordered by vote result (most popular comment at the top of the list).
I have installed [voting API](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi), [rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) and [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module. Then add a yes/no voting to comments and enable threading for comments in order to let users reply each other.

I created a views to show comments in most popular order with these sort criteria:

```
Comment: Thread (asc)
SUM(Votes: Value)
```

Now the problem is that when views tries to keep thread it sort theme by post date (asc/disc) and do not see the second sort criteria.

So how can I sort comments by vote results keeping threading?

EDIT:
[image: views config]

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your view config?

Comment: @longboardnode yes of course. I add it to my question

Comment: why are you using aggregation?

Comment: @NoSssweat because I need the summation of vote result. It doesn't effect the problem for sure.

Comment: What happens if you remove `Comment: Thread (asc)`?

Comment: @NoSssweat it does not keep threading of comments. Comments will be separated from their replies and it is not OK. I want to sort the comments which are at the root (have no parent) then their replies must come after them. That's all.

Comment: @shekoufeh so you want to sort the top-level comments by their ratings, and then sort their children comments under them according to the thread structure?

Comment: @longboardnode yes exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Main problem**

Currently there is no way to tie all the children and grandchildren comments to the Main Parent (original/first ever parent). Also, need a way to separate the Main parent from all the children.

**TL, DR Solution**

Use the Views field view module to separate the children from main parent, and add all children as a field. That way, we are able to sort Main Parent's by Votes without affecting the children and grandchildren.

But there is no way to just show all children and grandchildren of a Main Parent CID; therefore, create a custom module to solve this problem, so we can use the view field technique.

#### Detailed Solution

**Requirements**:

[Views field view](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view), [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity), Main PID (custom module below).

---

**main_pid.info**

```
name = Main PID
description = Links all children and grandchildren comments to the main parent by saving main parent cid into main_parent_pid field when comment is saved.
package = custom
core = 7.x
```

**main_pid.module**

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_comment_presave()
 */ 
function main_pid_comment_presave($comment) {
  
  $pid = $comment->pid;
  
  if ($pid > 0){
  
    while ($pid > 0) {
      // Implements comment_load()
      $load_comment = comment_load($pid);
  
      $pid = $load_comment->pid;
      $cid = $load_comment->cid;
      
    }
    
    $comment->field_main_pid[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $cid;
  
  }
  
  elseif ($pid == 0) {
    
    $comment->field_main_pid[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 0;
    
  }
  
}
```

Now in comments add a new field called Main PID with machine name of `field_main_pid`. You can do this programmatically or using the Drupal UI (I will leave this up to you)

[image]

Now, hide field from display

[image]

---

**In your view:**

In fields, add `Comment: Rendered Comment` (Thanks to Entity API)

[image]

In fields, add `Comment ID`

[image]

---

Now add a new block

[image]

Click on block, and change the display name

[image]

In fields add `Depth`

[image]

In fields, add `Comment: Rendered Comment` (Thanks to Entity API)

[image]

The style settings will allow you to indent the children with CSS.

Example:

```
.depth-1 { width: 480px; margin-left: 10px; }
.depth-2 { width: 470px; margin-left: 20px; }
```

In Filter Criteria, add `Content: Main PID`

[image]

Only the Main parent has PID of 0, therefore, this will show all the children only

Then add `Content: Thread` in Sort and `Main PID` in Contextual Filter

So your **Children View** should look like this:

[image]

---

**Going back to the first View**:

In Filter Criteria add Main PID

[image]

This time equal to 0, since we only want the main parents.

Now in Fields, add `Global: View` (Thanks to Views field View)

[image]

Your **Original/Main View** Should look like this:

**Important:** Add contextual filter of NID here (forgot to do that).

[image]

Lastly, In Sort Criteria, add the `Votes Value` (Not shown on screenshot since I did not bother to install Voting API and Rate) and remove the default `Post date`.

Comment: thanks alot for your complete answer. there is two problems: first, if I add fields in views one by one the vote API module does not work. I mean it works just when I use rendered entity. Second, I can not add a field to comments because I have three tabs sorting comments by oldest, newest and most popular. So the collection of requirements limits me and it is making me crazy.

Comment: @shekoufeh `I add fields in views one by one the vote API module does not work. I mean it works just when I use rendered entity` but in my answer the **`Comment: Rendered Comment`** field renders the entity (comment)... (no need to add fields one by one, title, body, etc..), so it should work here too. Did you try my answer out? `Second, I can not add a field to comments because I have three tabs sorting comments by oldest, newest and most popular.` On your screenshot I do not see this, also why would adding a field affect your tab?

Comment: How did you set Main PID in Contextual Filter? set it to "Display all results for the specified field " in Contextual Filter setting page?

Comment: @shekoufeh yep.

Comment: Thanks for your full answer. I tested it with a bit of change and worked great. You should just consider comment:nid in your Contextual Filter and use rules instead of news module.

Comment: the original list of comments need comment:nid in order to show comments of each node of themselves.

Comment: @shekoufeh ah right, for the original view. Since when I did my test I only had 1 node, didn't need to worry about that.